# Damas-Milner-like subset of the calculus of constructions with global type inference

Tags: lo.logic, pl.programming-languages, type-theory

Damas-Milner is a subset of System Fω that gives up expressivity (type-level computation) for usability (type inference). The experience with Haskell and ML attests to the practical value of this tradeoff.

Does a similar Damas-Milner-like subset of the calculus of constructions exist, for which global type inference is possible? I expect the answer to be “yes” based on the following clues:

- [1ML](https://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/1ml/)'s abstract syntax already unifies terms and types, in a way reminiscent of System Fω's definition as a pure type system, and then makes type inference work for a subset of the language.
- AFAICT, Damas-Milner type inference only requires that the type language be first-order, pure, terminating and confluent. First-order unification doesn't require that all unification variables range over a single sort (namely, that of types). A first-order, pure, terminating language can be carved out of a higher-order, effectful, potentially nonterminating language, by means of syntactic restrictions on terms in the latter.

But is there a definitive answer?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, 1ML is "sugar for plain System Fω". Haskell doesn't have fully kind inference, you need these $*$, $**$ etc.

Comment: @MartinBerger: Haskell has kind inference. What it doesn't have is polymorphic kinds, at least not without a GHC extension. So, at the end of the kind inference process, all remaining kind unification variables are unified with *.

Comment: @MartinBerger: System Fω can be presented in (at least) two ways: (0) with a stratified abstract syntax for kinds, types and terms (TAPL, pp. 450-451), or (1) as a pure type system, with a unified abstract syntax for all sorts (ATTAPL, pp. 72-73). 1ML is closer to the latter than to the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no prime candidate for an analogue of Damas-Milner for CoC. Certainly there is no *definitive answer*.

Arguably, Damas-Milner isn't even a perfect inference system for $\mathrm{F}_\omega$, as in general it can't infer types with higher kinds in them (though it is an open question as to whether higher kinds are really necessary, see [this problem](http://tlca.di.unito.it/opltlca/opltlcasu19.html#x24-34000)).

At any rate, here's a rather simple argument against a definitive system for the CoC: unification modulo $\beta$ conversion is undecidable in general, even for terms with simple types. But for a given unification problem $t\approx u$ it is rather easy to set up a term which can be typed if and only if $t$ unifies with $u$:

$$ A : \Pi \vec{x}.C\ t\rightarrow \mathrm{nat},\ B:\Pi\vec{x}.C\ u\vdash A\ B$$

where the $\vec{x}$ are the free (unification) variables in $t$ and $u$, as well as the "implicit arguments" which are the analogue of the polymorphic type variables in Damas-Milner.

That being said, there are restrictions of the unification problem which are decidable, most notably *Miller patterns* which have good properties (uniqueness of solutions), so it's common to restrict implicit argument resolution to Miller patterns and reject the term otherwise.

In practice every dependently typed language *does* have to solve this problem, if only because giving every single type annotation is unworkably tedious. However, that inference is usually designed to *fail* in which case the user is asked to supply additional annotations, something which is absent from usual programing language type inference systems.

More background in this cs.stackexchange answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12691/what-makes-type-inference-for-dependent-types-undecidable

and this one, more centered on the unification problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936432/higher-order-unification

And (tooting my own horn further, I guess), I recommend the article [Elaboration in Dependent Type Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04324) by de Moura *et al*, as a discussion of the issues involved.

Comment: @MartinBerger actually that's a common misconception! Just because system $F$ has undecidable type inference doesn't automatically imply undecidability for an extension. A trivial counter-example is the type system in which every term is typable. More representative examples are undecidable subsysems of (classical) propositional logic. That being said, I'd be very surprised if $F_1$ turned out to have decidable inference.

Comment: you are right of course. I've deleted the comment.

Comment: I think the comment is quite useful actually! This is a subtle point that someone had to clarify for me as well (it was Alexandre Miquel, I think?).

Comment: I was quite embarrassed about this mistake because I  have criticised others in the past who made it ... and then I make it myself. :(

Comment: "An expert is a man who's made all the mistakes you can make, in a narrow field". - Niels Bohr

Comment: I don't miss higher-kinded type constructors when programming in ML. Types parameterized by proper types (of kind `*` in Haskell) are good enough for my use cases. Similarly, in a dependently typed language, I don't need types parameterized by functions. Types parameterized by values of `eqtype`s are good enough for my use cases.

Comment: And I don't like the approach of allowing type inference to fail. I'm willing to use a less powerful type system, if that's what it takes to make type inference decidable.